# Where in a max-heap might the smallest element reside, assuming that all elements are distinct?

Tags: algorithm, heap

**Question**: Where in a max-heap might the smallest element reside, assuming that all elements are distinct?

I understand that in a max-heap, the largest node is the root and the smallest is one of the leaves. I found answer which says that it's in any of the any of the leaves, that is, elements with index `⌊n/2⌋+k`, where `k>=1` , that is, in the second half of the heap array.

**Problem**: can you please explain why the answer I found do not just say it's one of the leaves? Can you please explain why answer brough `⌊n/2⌋+k`? Second, why in the second half, when it's in the last level of the tree given that all parents are greater than their children, so a child at height 1 is smaller than parent but larger than its child and so on.

**Edited**: Can you please explain why the indices of the leaves are `⌊n/2⌋+1, ⌊n/2⌋+2, ..., ⌊n/2⌋+n`? Or why the index of the last non-leaf node is at `⌊n/2⌋` of array-based heap please? We know that total vertices of heap is given by `Ceil(n/2^(h+1))`. The leaves number is `Ceil(n/2)`, so hope the extra details would help solving the question.

Comment: Are you using zero-based or one-based indexing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a zero-based indexed array, the root is at index 0. The children of the root are at index 1 and 2. In general the children of index  are at indices 2+1 and 2+2.

So for a node to have children, we must have that 2+1 (i.e. the left child) is still within the range of the array, i.e. 2+1 < , where  is the size of the array (i.e. the last index is at -1).

Which is the index of the first leaf? That would be the least value of  for which 2+1 <  is not true, i.e. when 2+1 ≥ . From that we can derive that:

- All indices that represent leaves are grouped together. They are all at the , for which 2+1 ≥
- The least index of a leaf is at index  = <sub>⌊</sub>/2<sub>⌋</sub>.

If you are working with a one-based indexed array (as is common in pseudo code), then you can adapt the above reasoning to derive that the first leaf is at index  = <sub>⌊</sub>/2<sub>⌋</sub>+1.

So the answer you quote is assuming a 1-based indexed array, and then it is correct to say that the first leaf is positioned at <sub>⌊</sub>/2<sub>⌋</sub>+1, and *any* leaf is at a position <sub>⌊</sub>/2<sub>⌋</sub>+, where ≥1.

Comment: Thank you very much. I used 0-based. I realized that since nodes of heap are given by `n/2^(h+1)`, then the last node of non-leaf is `floor(n/2^(h+1))` and problem is solved. I can just increment `floor(n/2^(h+1))+1...floor(n/2^(h+1))`+n`

Comment: What is `h` in that formula? My answer shows that this is just dependent on `n`, not anything else.

Comment: `h` is the height of the heap. If `h=0` we can see it will give the leaves, when `h=1` it will give parents of leaves. So I used this fact to take `floor(n/2^(h+1))`. This is how I solved it.  Thanks again.

Comment: Oh ok, then indeed, `h=2` will give the grandparents... this is some aspect you didn't mention in the question.

Comment: Your question is OK. You could have shown more of the effort to find out where the index would be, given a few examples. Then you show effort, and that is always appreciate here. When upon a first read someone gets the impression there is lack of effort, they may downvote (and move on).

Comment: Thank you. I provided Edited part in the question to add more to the question.